# Alexa.Net cannot create a reminder: throws error

Tags: c#, alexa-skills-kit

While using the code base from the project to create a reminder, I get the following error:

> Error at Alexa.NET.Response.RemindersClient.d__8.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
>   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
>   at AlexaWebAPI.Controllers.ReminderController.d__0.MoveNext()

Sample code I am using:

```
try
{
    var reminder = new Reminder
    {
        RequestTime = DateTime.UtcNow,
        Trigger = new RelativeTrigger(12 * 60 * 60),
        AlertInformation = new AlertInformation(new[] {new SpokenContent("it's a test", "en-GB") }),
        PushNotification = PushNotification.Disabled
    };
    var client = new RemindersClient(RemindersClient.ReminderDomain,input.Session.User.AccessToken);
    var alertDetail = await client.Create(reminder);
    Trace.TraceInformation(alertDetail.AlertToken);
    return ResponseBuilder.Tell($"I would to create a reminder on ${date} .");
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Trace.TraceError(ex.StackTrace);
    return ResponseBuilder.Ask("Some error occured while creating reminder", null);
}
```

Comment: And what is the exception type and what does the exception _message_ say?

Comment: Unexpected result: Status Unauthorized, body: {"code":"INVALID_BEARER_TOKEN","message":"Invalid Bearer token"}. I have enabled reminder permission for my skill